# Get date and time from MS Access database using visual basic

Tags: date

Good day! I would like to ask what are the syntax in getting the date and time from the  MS Access database? the name of the database is "DatabaseTest", the name of the table is "Test" and the name of the field in the table is "schedDateTime". Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From where / which application are you trying to retrieve that info?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you interested in the time and date that a particular record was created, the easiest thing you can do is create a field named something like "EntryDate" set the date type to "Date/Time". Go under the field properties and select Format: " General Date" then type =now() into the Default Value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question could use a little clarification. Do you need help parsing a Date/time field, or do you need help figuring out what sql-type query to use?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim recSet As DAO.Recordset
    Dim searchID As Integer

    ' Set searchID to the ID you are looking for
    searchID = 1

    ' Set up the database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' Get the value from the database
    Set recSet = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [schedDateTime] FROM [Test] WHERE ([ID] =" & searchID & ")")

    ' Where textBox is the name of a text box in your form
    [textBox] = recSet(0)
End Sub
```

In the above, I have shown how to retrieve a value from a database and store it in a form. If this is similar to what you want, I am sure you can adjust the code to your needs.